# How to pass user name or user ip adress on jdbc connection?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

i have oracle users database. System has users on LDAP. And i want to keep user's log when user insert/update/delete. But how to pass user name or user ip and user password to oracle on jdbc connection?

i use weblogic. And system connection with just one user and password. This user is setting on weblogic generic data source.

my jdbc connection class is

```
public class DBFactory {
private static javax.sql.DataSource dataSource = null;

public static Connection getConnection(String user, String password) {
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            //weblogic app server
            javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();

            dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/XXXX");

        }   

        connection=dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=XTURKISH_AI");
        statement.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC");

        statement.close();
        return connection;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new DBFactoryException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

what can i do? or another solution?

Comment: Please clarify.  You want to connect to the db with the LDAP user's credentials, or you want to know which user did a DML?

Comment: ok i explain clearly. every table has trigger and this trigger insert log tables after insert/uptade/delete. Log table has activite_user field and default value is USER (Oracle User) But my jdbc connect just one user ( setting user= asdf on weblogic server). writing activite_user = asdf in every log record. It is problem. I want to use LDAP user getconnection(user,password) class. For example LDAP user is abc. Oracle user is abc. while user log on system, connection open with this user. Not asdf (setting weblogic's database user name)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an admin user, say asdf.  You want to get to the Oracle DB with the admin credentials.  This could be achieved using JNDI configured in Weblogic.  In Weblogic console go to  Services > Data Sources. Create a new generic data source, making sure to create a JNDI name () . Use default database driver. Fill in all needed connection information and test the database connectivity.  On the look up replace the string argument with the JNDI name you provided in the console, i.e. dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("");.

Comment: thanx to reply i solved problem.Firstly user connect getconnection() methods (not user,password parameter)  with asdf (weblogic user parameter), later when LDAP is get success, other process use getconnection ( user,password) methods. My fault is, when user connect firstly, call getconnection(user,password). Unless LDAP is succeess, jdbc not connect with oracle user,password. Firstly oracle need to connect to admin user. Thanx all reply